# Get data from measuring website only with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I'm trying to get data from this website https://www.dsl.cz/test-mereni-rychlosti.
(This website measure speed of internet).

**What I need to print:**

```
Test rychlosti připojení: 40
Test stahování připojení: 20
Poskytovatel internetu: Vodafone
```

**What i get:**

```
Test rychlosti připojení: <span id="download-result">...</span>
Test stahování připojení: <span id="upload-result">...</span>
Poskytovatel internetu: None
```

**My code:**

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.dsl.cz/test-mereni-rychlosti'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
time.sleep(1)

vysledek = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'results'})
for job_data in vysledek:

    #Výsledek stahování
    stahovani = job_data.find('span', attrs={"id":"download-result"})
    print("Test rychlosti připojení: " + str(stahovani))

    #Výsledek ukládání
    ukladani = job_data.find('span', attrs={"id":"upload-result"})
    print("Test stahování připojení: " + str(ukladani))

    #Poskytovatel
    poskytovatatel = job_data.find('id', attrs={"id":"provider-result"})
    print("Poskytovatel internetu: " + str(poskytovatatel))
```

What is wrong with my code? I have a problem with this web, because there is something calculate speed of internet and I dont know, if this need use only webdriver instead BeautifulSoup (which I really need).

Comment: That *something* is called JavaScript. The page is dynamic, which means `bs4` won't see those metrics.

Comment: I suggest you use a Selenium type solution here. The browser is carrying out the speed test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not so sure that that is possible with beautiful soup and requests. I tried something similar with google translate and it did not work. Try using `selenium`.

Comment: Ok, Thx for help.